# can elasticsearch context suggester be updated?

Tags: elasticsearch

I referred to [this PR](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/4044) to create suggestion as you type using elasticsearch completion type.

```
{
  "MyType": {
     "properties":{
            "MyField":{
                "type":"completion",
                "index_analyzer":"MyIndexAnalyzer",
                "search_analyzer":"MySearchAnalyzer",
                "payloads":true,
                "context": { 
                   "deleteFlag": { 
                      "type": "category", 
                      "path": "deleteFlag" 
                   }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that everything is working fine if I set context to the value of **deleteFlag** when indexing. 
When I use update query to change the value of **deleteFlag** it gets changed but when I query by filtering against the **deleteFlag** I am still getting result depending on the value of the **deleteFlag** when the doc was indexed.

Which makes me think that even updated context fields keep their previous value.

If so why? What am I not understanding well here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that it was a bug ([Issue on Github](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/7761)).